# what is structure of BotConfiguration.bot in bot project using bot framwork SDK4.0 and how to add it the project?

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-qna-maker

I am referring to the QnA bot sample from the git hub link [QnAbot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/11.qnamaker), but when I follow the steps, I am not able to figure it out the BotConfiguration.bot. I want to see the sample of this .bot file. However, from in the sample code directory, I did not find it.

Can someone tell me how to create a simple QnA bot using SDK4.0?

I am using C# .net core bot template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easier way to generate Bot Configuration file without typing all these commands.

a) Install [Bot Framework Emulator](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases)

b) Launch the emulator, Navigate to "File" and select "New Bot Configuration".

c) After key in all the information needed, just save the file at your desired location.

p/s: The sample botConfiguraton.bot file can refer to the official [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-qna?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs).

Answer (score 1):

In order to auto generate a bot file you have to use [botbuilder-tools](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools).  For some reason the instructions are missing in that samples readme  I will work on getting that updated ASAP.

You can install the tools by running this command in command line:

```
npm install -g chatdown msbot ludown luis-apis qnamaker botdispatch luisgen
```

You will need to have there installed:

- Node.js version 8.5 or higher
- .NET Core SDK version 2.1.403 or higher

Then you will have to run the `msbot init` command with the options you need, a list of options can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/blob/master/packages/MSBot/docs/create-bot.md)

and an example command would look like this:

```
msbot init --name TestBot --endpoint http://localhost:9499/api/messages
```

Then you will need to add the qnamaker service, there is information about adding this and other services [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/blob/master/packages/MSBot/docs/add-services.md)

an example of the command you would run to add the qnamaker service would look like this:

```
msbot connect qna --name "<NAME>" --kbId <KNOWLEDGE BASE ID> --subscriptionKey <SUBSCRIPTION KEY> --endpointKey <ENDPOINT-KEY> --hostname "https://myqna.azurewebsites.net"
```

When you are done you will have a .bot file that will look like this:

```
{
    "name": "qnamaker2",
    "services": [
        {
            "type": "endpoint",
            "name": "qnamaker2",
            "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978/api/messages",
            "appId": "",
            "appPassword": "",
            "id": "0"
        },
        {
            "type": "qna",
            "name": "{YOUR QnA APP NAME}",
            "kbId": "{YOUR KNOWLEDGEBASE ID}",
            "subscriptionKey": "{YOUR SUBSCRIPTION KEY}",
            "endpointKey": "{your endpoint key}",
            "hostname": "{YOUR HOSTNAME}",
            "id": "74"
        }
    ],
    "padlock": "",
    "version": "2.0"
}
```